# Getting values of each row of a html table and storing in a variable to be used later

Tags: javascript, jquery

On the click event of a button I am reading the rows of a html table
and all I get with the alert is shown in the attached image.

I want to be able to get the value highlighted in yellow and store in a variable.
How can I achieve that?

```
$(document).on("click", "#AMeter", function () {               
    $('#Meters1 .numval').each(function () {
        alert($(this).html());
    });
});
```

[image: screen shot of result]

Comment: `$(this).find('input').val()`

Comment: can you provide a demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find()` to get the `input` within `#AMeter` and then `val()` to get its value:

```
$(document).on("click", "#AMeter", function () {               
    $('#Meters1 .numval').each(function () {
        var numval = $(this).find('input').val();

        // use numval here...
    });
});
```

Alternatively, if you want to build an array of all the `.numval` values in the row, you can use `map()`:

```
$(document).on("click", "#AMeter", function () {               
    var values = $('#Meters1 .numval input').map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get();

    // use values here...
});
```